# HIVE JOIN two tables with different number of rows giving wrong column values

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive, hiveql

I am relatively new to Hive. Exploring on ways to merge two tables that are not connected to each other by keys. So, I have not used 'ON' condition in the query.

The below is table_1 :

```
COL1
hello
```

The below is table_2 :

```
COL2
world
excellent
```

EXPECTED RESULT :

```
hello world
NULL  excellent
```

ACTUAL RESULT :

```
hello world
hello excellent
```

My Query :

```
select col_one,
    col_two
from (
    select COL1 as col_one
    from table_1
    ) as c1
join (
    select COL2 as col_two
    from table_2
    ) as c2;
```

I'm not sure from how the 'hello' in the result comes when there is no row-2 in table_1

Comment: Because you are doing cross join - `1 x 2 = 2 rows`. What's your criteria of joining or as you said, "merging"? By looking at your data there seems none.

Comment: Hi @GurwinderSingh : These tables are not related by keys. So in my case i have not giving any condition.

Comment: You can't join in that way. Do you have any order in mind? perhaps in ascending order of the two columns and then joined on row number?

Comment: Is it possible to arrive at my expected result using JOIN ?

Comment: Oh.. If that's the case. I will try revisiting my join conditions as well. Thanks for your help @GurwinderSingh

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @GurV , I have decided to go with writing my own mapreduce code as I had to do lot more apart from joining tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your query works without an `on` clause.  But, you can do what you want using `row_number()`, something like this:

```
select c1.col_one, c2.col_two
from (select COL1 as col_one, row_number() over (order by col1) as seqnum
      from table_1
     ) c1 join
     (select COL2 as col_two, row_number() over (order by col2) as seqnum
      from table_2
     ) c2
     on c1.seqnum = c2.seqnum;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Gordon , I have decided to go with writing my own mapreduce code as I had to do lot more apart from joining tables.